# Backup 'empty' parts of disk drive

Tags: hard-disk, dd

I have a USB drive which has around 7MB of 'empty' space at its beginning. The first partition in MBR starts at 8225kB, according to Parted.

How can I back up this space using something like `dd`? I've already backed up the MBR table using `dd if=/dev/sdX bs=512 count=1 of=device.mbr`. How can I give dd a byte range in the disk to grab and then write that locally to a file on disk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `skip` flag, `bs` flag, and `count` flag, you can control how much data dd reads in and when to start.
`dd if=/dev/sdX bs=1M count=7 skip=1 of=test.img`
That command would start off at the second Megabyte of the disk, and backup seven megabytes.